# Romantic French movie about a gay guy acting in love with a girl for the sake of his parents?

Tags: identify-this-movie

I watched this movie a very long time ago, it's possible this movie came out in late 90's or beginning of 00's.

Movie language is French.

The first scene of the movie is a family gathering.there's this guy and girl their parents believe lovers. because they live together. they are in collage age.

later in the movie, viewers get to know the boy is Gay,and he's only pretending in love with the girl because he's scared what his parents might think. and the girl also know this and also support him to conceal who he really is.

Then he meets a guy he could be a collage student or teacher I don't remember that part correctly but his name is Cedric. They fall in love and other boy stays at Cedric's home as I remember.

Near the end  there's a scene Cedric's mother meet with other boys mother and tell her about their relationship, Cedric's mother approves way he is.

another highlight I remember about it is two boys get in to a  big fight and there was smashing of glasses and stuff.

This was one of the most romantic movies I've watched, I specially loved the way they fall in to each other and the main character embracing who he really is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possibly [Juste une question d'amour](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0231844/) (Just a Question of Love) - a French/Belgian movie from 2000.

Synopsis:

> After his gay cousin dies from hepatitis, young Laurent, who lives with his best friend Carole, falls in love with Cedric, a plant scientist. He's afraid to inform his conservative parents that he is gay.

Movie: